# How do I register a custom URL protocol in Windows?

Tags: windows, url, protocols, custom-url-protocol

How do I register a custom protocol with Windows so that when clicking a link in an email or on a web page my application is opened and the parameters from the URL are passed to it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I create my own URL protocol? (e.g. so://...)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so)

Comment: If you are using python, you can install [simpler](https://pypi.org/project/simpler/) and use [register_protocol_handler](https://simpler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/simpler.terminal.html#simpler.terminal.register_protocol_handler).

Answer (score 158):

1. Go to `Start` then in `Find` type `regedit` -> it should open Registry editor
2. Click <kbd>Right Mouse</kbd> on `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` then `New` -> `Key`

[image]

3. In the Key give the lowercase name by which you want urls to be called (in my case it will be `testus://sdfsdfsdf`) then Click <kbd>Right Mouse</kbd> on `testus` ->  then `New` -> `String Value` and add `URL Protocol` without value.

[image]

4. Then add more entries like you did with protocol ( <kbd>Right Mouse</kbd> `New` -> `Key` ) and create hierarchy like `testus` -> `shell` -> `open` -> `command` and inside `command` change `(Default)` to the path where `.exe` you want to launch is, if you want to pass parameters to your exe then wrap path to exe in `""` and add  `"%1"` to look like: `"c:\testing\test.exe" "%1"`

[image]

5. To test if it works go to Internet Explorer (not Chrome or Firefox) and enter `testus:have_you_seen_this_man` this should fire your `.exe` (give you some prompts that you want to do this - say Yes) and pass into args `testus://have_you_seen_this_man`.

Here's sample console app to test:

```
using System;

namespace Testing
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args!= null && args.Length > 0)
            Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this saves you some time.

Comment: Wow this thing works. And not only on IE but also on Chrome!

Comment: Any way to do this in C#? Like an installer...?

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius can I specify "working directory for the application to run from" in registry(within custom URL protocol entry). Ex. for triggering a Batch file if I create a custom Url registry entry, the batch file runs from system32 when launched from browser irrespective of the location of the batch file, whereas if I run the batch file by double clicking it, then the working directory remains its current directory.

Comment: @user1066231 https://superuser.com/questions/396394/how-do-i-set-an-executables-working-directory-via-the-command-line-prior-to-ex ?

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius Thanks. yeah found the answer. posting here-may be usefull for someone else.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68577785/how-to-make-url-protocol-to-launch-application-from-its-own-directory-instead?noredirect=1#comment121226027_68577785

Comment: I've followed these steps, and using custom protocol "testus:foo" gets recognized from Run dialog in windows 7, but not from any of the browsers I tried, nor from the cmd shell. Any idea on what I could have done wrong or missed?

Comment: Waiting for someone to just post the .reg file

Comment: @WiiLF that would be a nice answer, you are welcome to use the stuff above to write it. I promise a +1 if you do.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in a cross-platform way? If not, how can it be done on Mac and Linux?

Comment: This doesn't work when I try to open a file with notepad. Notepad opens but with an empty text editor and an error message (https://imgur.com/MmXwxHL). Here is my setup https://imgur.com/pbb3v4D (I tried without the "" around %1 and adding another "" before "%1", without success).

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius I posted the reg file

Comment: I did these steps but my program does not seem to run. I get the prompt about what this URL wants to open on my computer, this is ok. But I click OK and nothing happens. The app is supposed to create a log file and write the URL in it, but no file is created. Anybody has any idea what can be the problem?

Comment: @pedro put the breakpoint and see if your `Main` method gets hit, if not then most likely something with PATH to `.exe`. Could be a number of things like permissions and such.

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius any ideas how to do this with multiple commands such as in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77354186/register-custom-url-protocol-with-multiple-commands

Comment: Can i make the application launches only once if there is already running application?

Comment: Hi @MatasVaitkevicius, thanks this helps a lot was able to launch for custom url. I need your help how can we do it for https urls? Let's say I have my domain for example ("https:// abc.com") As I see in the registry https has default browser so we shouldn't modify that. Can we do some changes in the registry where with the help of domain abc.com if the application is installed it gives the pop up to launch the application?  I don't want all https links but only to my domain "abc.com"

Answer (score 23):

[Obsolete - the MSDN information has been replaced by a [new page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) which does address the security concerns]

The MSDN link is nice, but the security information there isn't complete. The handler registration should contain "%1", not %1. This is a security measure, because some URL sources incorrectly decode %20 before invoking your custom protocol handler.

PS. You'll get the entire URL, not just the URL parameters. But the URL might be subject to some mistreatment, besides the already mentioned %20->space conversion. It helps to be conservative in your URL syntax design. Don't throw in random // or you'll get into the mess that file:// is.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "mess that the file://" is?

Comment: There's no formal mapping of file: URLs to local paths. There's not even a consensus on the use of two or three leading slashes, or the use of forward versus backward slashes when the path refers to a Windows directory.

Comment: Late comment, I know. But is it also possible to somehow access the URL parameters *only*, without the protocol handler?

Comment: That sounds like a separate question. Please do get your terms straight, though. The protocol handler is the program that receives the URL. "Without the protocol handler" there's nobody to parse the URL and access the URL parameters.

Comment: Wrapping the path or the parameter in quotes makes no difference to the registry validity, some installers do it either way

Comment: @WiiLF: Correct, the registry treats it as just a `REG_SZ`. And internally, Windows doesn't parse command lines so spaces are preserved as well. But any language runtime that parses a command line (such as C's `argv[]`parsing) will break on an unquoted space.

Comment: This answer appears to be referring to an MSDN link that isn't in the question or this answer.  Answers should be fully self contained and not rely on external links nor should they reference links that aren't specifically part of the question.

Answer (score 20):

If anyone wants a .reg file for creating the association, see below:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\duck]
"URL Protocol"=""
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\duck\shell]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\duck\shell\open]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\duck\shell\open\command] 
@="\"C:\\Users\\duck\\source\\repos\\ConsoleApp1\\ConsoleApp1\\bin\\Debug\\net6.0\\ConsoleApp1.exe\" \"%1\""
```

Paste that into notepad, then file -> save as -> duck.reg, and then run it. After running it, when you type `duck://arg-here` into chrome, ConsoleApp1.exe will run with "arg-here" as an argument. Double slashes are required for the path to the exe and double quotes must be escaped.

Tested and working on Windows 11 with Edge (the chrome version) and Chrome

Comment: what happens if the registration already exists? does this `reg` override it?

Comment: @NitinSawant Yes, if it already exists it will override it.

Answer (score 8):

There is an npm module for this purpose.

link :https://www.npmjs.com/package/protocol-registry

So to do this in nodejs you just need to run the code below:

First Install it

```
npm i protocol-registry
```

Then use the code below to register you entry file.

```js
const path = require('path');

const ProtocolRegistry = require('protocol-registry');

console.log('Registering...');
// Registers the Protocol
ProtocolRegistry.register({
    protocol: 'testproto', // sets protocol for your command , testproto://**
    command: `node ${path.join(__dirname, './index.js')} $_URL_`, // $_URL_ will the replaces by the url used to initiate it
    override: true, // Use this with caution as it will destroy all previous Registrations on this protocol
    terminal: true, // Use this to run your command inside a terminal
    script: false
}).then(async () => {
    console.log('Successfully registered');
});
```

Then suppose someone opens testproto://test
then a new terminal will be launched executing :

```
node yourapp/index.js testproto://test
```

It also supports all other operating system.

Comment: Is there a cross-platform tool like this available as a C++ library?

Comment: Hi there is a cli version of this available as "protocol-registry-cli"  You can use it and run it through c++

Answer (score 1):

To further the existing answers a bit more, the application invoked to handle the protocol does not have to be a compiled application. It can also be a script file.

For example, you could create a Windows batch file - such as that below to - handle the call. Let us assume you save that script to `c:\temp\testprotocol-handler.bat`.

```
REM just echo the passed argument
echo off
echo Hello from the custom protocol handling script.
echo script name: %0
echo script arg : %1
pause
```

Use the following registry configuration to map the script to the protocol `testprotocol`.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\testprotocol]
"URL Protocol"=""
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\testprotocol\shell]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\testprotocol\shell\open]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\testprotocol\shell\open\command] 
@="\"C:\\temp\\testprotocol-handler.bat\" \"%1\""
```

When the OS encounters the protocol it will execute the script - opening a command window and displaying the content of the `echo` statements in the script.

[sample script executing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipnNl.png)

Comment: Reminder to put double-backslash for each path separator in the .REG script.