# How to run a shell script on a user machine after calling the script through url

Tags: php, python, bash, shell, shell-exec

I have a script called `xyz.sh` which uses zenity.which when executed gives the users  a selection menu.issue is this is one of our team mate `/home/dir` which is nfs based.
usally we run the `path/xyz.sh` from terminal.it gets executed. What i was trying to make this as a url and which when called by the user should run the script and pops the selection menu.

example : `http://abc.com/xyz` which should execute the `xyz.sh` on user remote machine. not on server.

i don't mind if it is in python or in cgi/php.

---

Update:
Thanks for sharing the link.I have tried and created protocol handler in firefox. As mentioned the below.

First open `about:config` and then I have created a external protocol. `network.protocol-handler.external.app.xyz.sh` and in the string I have provided the path of my script `/home/xyz/xyz.sh`

But, when I call this from the browser xyz: it is again giving me error as "firefox does know how to open this address. Because protocol is not associated with any programme".

Please help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to run an arbitrary script on a visitors computer (for obvious reasons).

The best approach is probably to tell the user to install some software, which registers a custom protocol in the browser, so that you can direct the user to something like

```
pythonexec://abc.com/xyz
```

How to do this is explained in other SO posts such as this one:

- [how do I create my own URL protocol? (e.g. so://...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so)
- [Custom protocol in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411544/custom-protocol-in-linux) (for linux)

Comment: One more things which i forgot to add is .All the users machines runs linux oses.which by default installed with python2.6

Comment: Added a url to another question.