# How to register a url protocol handler in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cross-platform, protocol-handler

I am developing a command line node module and would like to be able to launch it via links on a website.

I want to register a custom protocol `my-module://` such that links would have the following format: `my-module://action:some-action` and clicking on them would start the node package.

If there isn't a node API for this (I'm sure there won't be) then is there a way I can do it from node by invoking system commands?

It must work on Windows, Linux, and MacOS.

Comment: This wouldn't be a Node API, this would be a browser setting.

Comment: @hexacyanide Url protocols are handled by the OS not the browser, I have successfully implemented it for Windows (you have to add some registry keys) but wanted to know if there was a cross-platform node API rather than separately implementing each platform.

Comment: This would seem to be inconsistent as protocol handlers can be added in both Chrome and Firefox with just settings.

Comment: @hexacyanide They have their own wrapper around the system protocols so websites can register themselves (chrome then registers itself as the handler), if you look at the chrome or firefox handlers it will only display the ones defined from within each of them - if a handler isn't in it's internal settings then it will use the system handlers. spotify, github, itunes for example won't be listed there.

Comment: I am confused you say this is done by OS. What has this to do with node.js. Is the question similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411544/custom-protocol-in-linux

Comment: can't you just open an html file in the default browser that then runs a registerProtocolHandler() command? or open a url you control if file:/// is a no-go script-wise... i believe #start "http://..." works in windows...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Its an interesting idea.  I don't think there is currently a cross platform node.js solution out there.  I did come across this thread of people asking for the same thing:

```
https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/issues/951
```

Electron now supports it with the [`app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient`](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/#appsetasdefaultprotocolclientprotocol-path-args-macos-windows) API ([since v0.37.4](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/tag/v0.37.4)) for macOS and Windows.

It wouldn't be terribly difficult to write the library to do this.

**Windows**:

On the windows side you'd have to register the app as the application that handles that URI scheme.

You'll need to set up a registry entry for your application:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
   alert
      (Default) = "URL:Alert Protocol"
      URL Protocol = ""
      DefaultIcon
         (Default) = "alert.exe,1"
      shell
         open
            command
               (Default) = "C:\Program Files\Alert\alert.exe" "%1"
```

Then, when your application is run by windows, you should be able to see the arguments in `process.argv[]`.  Make sure that you launch a shell to run node, not just your application directly.

[Original MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(VS.85).aspx)

Note this requires administrator privileges and sets the handler system-wide. To do it per user, you can use `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` instead, as the Electron's implementation [does it](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/4ec7cc913d840ee211a92afa13f260681d8bf8f9/atom/browser/browser_win.cc#L203).

**Apple:**

The cited "OS X" article in the github comment is actually for iOS.  I'd look at the following programming guide for info on registering an application to handle a URL scheme:

[Apple Dev Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCConcepts/LSCConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000999-CH202-CIHFEEAD)

In summary, you'll need to create a launch service and populate the .plist file with `CFBundleURLTypes`, this field is an array and should be populated with just the protocol name i.e. `http`

The following [Super User Question](https://superuser.com/questions/548119/how-do-i-configure-custom-url-handlers-on-os-x) has a better solution, but is a per user setting.

"The file you seek is ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist.

It holds an array called LSHandlers, and the Dictionary children that define an LSHandlerURLScheme can be modified accordingly with the LSHandlerRole."

**Linux:**

From what I can tell, there are several ways to accomplish this in Linux (surprise?)

Gnome has a tool that will let you register a url handler [w3 archives](http://people.w3.org/~dom/archives/2005/09/integrating-a-new-uris-scheme-handler-to-gnome-and-firefox/)

```
gconftool-2 -t string -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/tel/command "bin/vonage-call %s"
gconftool-2 -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/tel/needs_terminal false -t bool
gconftool-2 -t bool -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/tel/enabled true
```

Some of the lighter weight managers look like they allow you to create fake mime types and register them as URI Protocol handlers.

"Fake mime-types are created for URIs with various scheme like this:
application/x-xdg-protocol-
Applications supporting specific URI protocol can add the fake mime-type to their MimeType key in their desktop entry files. So it's easy to find out all applications installed on the system supporting a URI scheme by looking in mimeinfo.cache file. Again defaults.list file can be used to specify a default program for speficied URI type." [wiki.lxde.org](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/Desktop_Preferred_Applications_Specification)

KDE also supports their own method of handling URL Protocol Handlers:

Create a file:  `$KDEDIR/share/services/your.protocol` and populate it with relevant data:

```
[Protocol]
exec=/path/to/player "%u"
protocol=lastfm
input=none
output=none
helper=true
listing=
reading=false
writing=false
makedir=false
deleting=false
```

from [last.fm forums](http://www.last.fm/forum/21714/_/42837/1#f430232) of all places

Hope that helps.

Comment: Okay, that seems to answer the MacOS and Windows parts.  If you can provide more information about Linux, including how it would work on systems using lighter desktop environments, for example, XFCE and LXDE on Linux; I'll award the bounty.  (Also, this is largely link based, so please quote those resources in case of link rot.)

Comment: From research, it looks like Windows probably handles this the best, on the Mac side it shouldn't be too difficult.  On the linux side, if you know what the end user will be using you should be able to find a happy median and maybe luck out with one of the systems that works.  This would be an AWESOME npm module, if you end up creating something, PM me about it, I'd love to see it!  I'd even be willing to throw in a hand with coding and testing.

Comment: Great!  This helps a lot.  I think I'll wrap all of this up in a node module, and I'll put another comment here when it's done.  I won't be able to do this for a little while, though.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I did on Mac OS with an application NW.js :

1. Open the app `/Applications/Utilities/Script Editor`

   type the following code in the editor

   ```
   on open location this_URL
      do shell script "/Applications/X.app/Contents/MacOS/x '" & this_URL & "'"
   end open location
   ```

   Replace *X* by the name of your App.

   Save the script as an *Application Bundle* anywhere
2. Go to the script, right click then '*Show Package Contents*' then edit `Contents/info.plist`

   Add these lines at the end of the file, just before `</dict></plist>` :

   ```
   <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
   <string>com.mycompany.AppleScript.AppName</string> <!-- edit here -->
   <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
   <array>
     <dict>
       <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
       <string>AppName</string> <!-- edit here -->
       <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
       <array>
         <string>myurlscheme</string> <!-- your url scheme here -->
       </array>
     </dict>
   </array>
   ```
3. You can now open a link starting with *myurlscheme:* and see your app is opening!

Comment: So you make an app to open another app?
Why not just put those info.plist files in the info.plist of the app you want to open? Would that not work for some reason?

Answer (score 3):

#### Edit :

Looks like the module has changed the registration process for good:

```js
const path = require('path');

const ProtocolRegistry = require('protocol-registry');

console.log('Registering...');
// Registers the Protocol
ProtocolRegistry.register({
    protocol: 'testproto', // sets protocol for your command , testproto://**
    command: `node ${path.join(__dirname, './tester.js')} $_URL_`, // this will be executed with a extra argument %url from which it was initiated
    override: true, // Use this with caution as it will destroy all previous Registrations on this protocol
    terminal: true, // Use this to run your command inside a terminal
    script: false
}).then(async () => {
    console.log('Successfully registered');
});
```

#### Original Answer :

There is an npm module for this purpose.

link :https://www.npmjs.com/package/protocol-registry

So to do this in nodejs you just need to run the code below:

First Install it

```
npm i protocol-registry
```

Then use the code below to register you entry file.

```js
const path = require('path');

const ProtocolRegistry = require('protocol-registry');

console.log('Registering...');
// Registers the Protocol
ProtocolRegistry.register({
    protocol: 'testproto', // set your app for testproto://**
    command: `node ${path.join(__dirname, './index.js')}`, // this will be executed with a extra argument %url from which it was initiated
}).then(async () => {
    console.log('Successfully registered');
});
```

Then suppose someone opens testproto://test
then a new terminal will be launched executing :

```
node yourapp/index.js testproto://test
```