# How to launch my electron app from a website

Tags: electron, electron-builder

We have an electron crypto app that signs transactions (among other things).

We want other websites to have the ability to have a button that opens that electron app, pre-filled with some params (the transaction information).

flow is:

1. user clicks "make transaction" on some-crypto-site.com
2. electron app opens up with pre-filled params
3. user clicks "sign transaction" in electron app
4. electron app does stuff behind the scenes
5. electron app closes and sends a message to some-crypto-site.com

This could be done at runtime, or install time.

## What I tried (linux, chrome)

calling [`app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appsetasdefaultprotocolclientprotocol-path-args) with the code of [this gist](https://gist.github.com/LucaBlackDragon/73428056388d7ee233c15fdebc6c7d71), which is basically:

```
app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient("my-app")
```

But after I put `my-app://foo?bar=baz` in chrome browser, I get the following popup, and pressing open-xdg does nothing (other than dismissing the popup)

[image]

## I looked into

1. Electron [protocol api](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/protocol) which seems to handle in-app protocols only
2. [webtorrent .desktop file](https://github.com/webtorrent/webtorrent-desktop/blob/73d5a4e1ab47c7139df836f4b7755f332d00a9c4/static/webtorrent.desktop#L16) This might be the way to go, I'm just not sure how to go about it.

Maybe there's a way to do so at install time through [electron builder](https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration)?

Thanks in advance for the help, I have no idea how to proceed here!

## Resources that might be useful

1. [github repo with mac+window example](https://github.com/oikonomopo/electron-deep-linking-mac-win)
2. [github comment for linux](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/4857#issuecomment-200608167)
3. [github comment for linux 2](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/4857#issuecomment-201124281)
4. [SO answer for all 3 OSs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534591/how-to-register-a-url-protocol-handler-in-node-js)
5. [SO windows answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so)
6. [npm package for windows registery](https://github.com/CatalystCode/windows-registry-node)
7. [SO mac answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471581/how-to-map-a-custom-protocol-to-an-application-on-the-mac)
8. [SO linux answer](https://superuser.com/questions/162092/how-can-i-register-a-custom-protocol-with-xdg)
9. [microsoft docs for windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85))
10. [windows article](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)
11. [github comment for windows](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/951#issuecomment-196177859)
12. [github comment for mac](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/3847)
13. [info.plst for mac](https://github.com/tinybug/electron-example/blob/master/Info.plist)
14. [old repo for mac and win](https://github.com/masahirompp/electron-open-url-sample)

Comment: call `app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient("my-app")`, then open it with `my-app://foo?bar=baz` result in call "your/path/electron.exe my-app://foo?bar=baz" . An delectron.exe will take its first argument as app path, so it's not working.

Comment: @hiitiger Thanks for commenting, I don't understand what you say. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 65):

Since this may be relevant to what I’m doing at work, I decided to give it a go.
I’ve only tested this on OSX though!

I looked at the documentation for [app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appsetasdefaultprotocolclientprotocol-path-args) and it says this:

> Note: On macOS, you can only register protocols that have been added to your app's info.plist, which can not be modified at runtime. You can however change the file with a simple text editor or script during build time. Please refer to Apple's documentation for details.

These protocols can be defined when packaging your app with `electron-builder`. See `build`:

```json
{
  "name": "foobar",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "dist": "electron-builder"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^3.0.7",
    "electron-builder": "^20.38.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "build": {
    "appId": "foobar.id",
    "mac": {
      "category": "foo.bar.category"
    },
    "protocols": {
      "name": "foobar-protocol",
      "schemes": [
        "foobar"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In your main thread:

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');

let mainWindow;

function createWindow () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html');
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

var link;

// This will catch clicks on links such as <a href="foobar://abc=1">open in foobar</a>
app.on('open-url', function (event, data) {
  event.preventDefault();
  link = data;
});

app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient('foobar');

// Export so you can access it from the renderer thread
module.exports.getLink = () => link;
```

In your renderer thread:

*Notice the use of the [remote](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/remote) API to access the `getLink` function exported in the main thread*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Received this data <input id="data"/></p>
    <script>
      const {getLink} = require('electron').remote.require('./main.js');
      document.querySelector('#data').value = getLink();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Example**

```html
<a href="foobar://abc=1">open in foobar</a>
```

[image]

This also allows you to launch from the command line:

```
open "foobar://xyz=1"
```

[image]

**How do you get back to the original caller?**

I suppose that when you launch the app you could include the caller url:

```html
<a href="foobar://abc=1&caller=example.com”>open in foobar</a>
```

When your electron app finishes processing data, it would simply ping back that url

**Credits**

Most of my findings are based on:

- From this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/4857)
- And the [excellent work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43912119/1244884) from @oikonomopo

Comment: Fantastic, will look into it ASAP! Did this work for you on development, or did you have to produce an installer and install it to make this work on your local machine?

Thanks again!

Comment: I haven't tried actually. This was indeed tested against a packaged and installed app.

Comment: On linux I've tried with a zippped packaged app, and it doesn't work. At the moment we are not using an installer for linux, so can't test that. Will update if we get this to work.

Comment: Note that the `open-url` event is mac only. Windows and Linux will need to use the argv param of `process.argv` to loop through the params and check if one of them is the url that was used to launch the app.

Comment: I am just wondering how would you dubug this kind of application?

Comment: Thanks a lot. You have shed light with clear explanation

Comment: Thanks @customcommander.  It may amuse you to know that this is still relevant to what you were doing at work 5 years ago!
I didn't realise that the package.json `build.protocols` actually _produces_ the necessary Info.plist entries.

Answer (score 1):

All little bit different from above.

open-url fires before the ready event so you can store it in a variable and use within the widow did-finish-load.

```
let link;

let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1280,
        height: 720,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false
        }
    });
    mainWindow.openDevTools();
    mainWindow.setContentProtection(true);
    mainWindow.loadFile('index.html');
    mainWindow.webContents.on("did-finish-load", function() {
        mainWindow.webContents.send('link', link);
    });
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

// This will catch clicks on links such as <a href="protocols://abc=1">open in foobar</a>
app.on('open-url', function(event, url) {
    link = url;
    if (mainWindow?.webContents) {
        mainWindow.webContents.send('link', link);
    }
});

app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient('protocols');
```

You can then use the value in your render html like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script>
            const ipc = require("electron").ipcRenderer;
            ipc.on("link", function (event, url) {
                console.log(url);
                console.log(parseQuery(decodeURI(url)));
            });
            function parseQuery(queryString) {
                queryString = queryString.substring(queryString.indexOf("://") + 3);
                var query = {};
                var pairs = (queryString[0] === "?" ? queryString.substr(1) : queryString).split("&");
                for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
                    var pair = pairs[i].split("=");
                    query[decodeURIComponent(pair[0])] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1] || "");
                }
                return query;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried the above steps in windows, throws me an error stating the unable to find electron app.. any suggestions?

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. To explain the value here: the `open-url` event may arrive either **before** or **after** the main window is initialized, depending on whether the URL was the reason the app launched. For the **before** case, we save the URL to be handled later in `did-finish-load`; for the **after** case, we handle it immediately (as `mainWindow` is no longer `undefined`).