# Web service to interact with running electron app

Tags: web-services, raspberry-pi, electron

I looking for some advice on the best way to set up a project. Not sure if this is the right place to ask but I will give it a go.

I am looking to create a "Smart Mirror". I know there are options already available for this but I want to go through the process of creating my own.

I have created the UI using electron and I am using this on a raspberry pi 3b+ using raspian stretch.

Now this is where my knowledge is lacking, due to no experience and not sure if what search terms to look for.

I would like to create a plug in on Chrome(used on my mobile phone) or a process that runs separately, to say "Send page/video to Smart Mirror". What I envisage is that this plug in will copy the URL for the page or the video and send this via a web service call. The running electron app on my raspberry pi will receive this call and process the URL and then display the page/video within a portion of the application.

I have only ever consumed a web service from within an application.

I am not sure how to set this up. Can my electron app be set up to receive this call? If so what search terms should I be looking for?

I hope this makes sense.

Please let me know your thoughts or if I am thinking about this all wrong

Comment: You may find this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53530726/1244884) useful.

Comment: I am also trying to do something similar but my problem is that I can not run it on device pi3 b+ I only have raspbian light with minimal x-server and i am packaging an app using packager. I do not want to install node on pi because that's not a standard way to deliver apps so maybe you can share your approach?