# How can i launch the ElectronJs Desktop App when user click some link in Website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I have Desktop app built using Electron js .
I have one website running .
My question :- When user try to click some link in our website
i want to launch the my Desktop app and load the link url in the Desktop app.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to launch my electron app from a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53530726/how-to-launch-my-electron-app-from-a-website)

Comment: yaa it is.. but its only happen when install app ..I want to show download option if its not already intalled.