# How to lauch my Electron app from a website

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, electron, vite

I´m building an App in the web using React-Vite with Typescript and i want to lauch an Electron-React-Vite-TS app when i click a button in the web App.

I ask to ChatGPT and it answered me that i need to declare a custom protocol in my main file at the electron app.

But i´m having problems trying to lauch the app.

My main.ts file looks like this:

```
import { protocol, app, shell, BrowserWindow } from 'electron'
import { join } from 'path'
import { electronApp, optimizer, is } from '@electron-toolkit/utils'
import icon from '../../resources/icon.png?asset'

// * Register custom Protocol

protocol.registerSchemesAsPrivileged([
  { scheme: 'myApp', privileges: { standard: true, secure: true } }
])

function createWindow(): void {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 900,
    height: 670,
    show: false,
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    ...(process.platform === 'linux' ? { icon } : {}),
    webPreferences: {
      preload: join(__dirname, '../preload/index.js'),
      sandbox: false
    }
  })

  mainWindow.on('ready-to-show', () => {
    mainWindow.show()
  })

  mainWindow.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler((details) => {
    shell.openExternal(details.url)
    return { action: 'deny' }
  })

  // HMR for renderer base on electron-vite cli.
  // Load the remote URL for development or the local html file for production.
  if (is.dev && process.env['ELECTRON_RENDERER_URL']) {
    mainWindow.loadURL(process.env['ELECTRON_RENDERER_URL'])
  } else {
    mainWindow.loadFile(join(__dirname, '../renderer/index.html'))
  }
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  // Set app user model id for windows
  electronApp.setAppUserModelId('com.electron')

  // Default open or close DevTools by F12 in development
  // and ignore CommandOrControl + R in production.
  // see https://github.com/alex8088/electron-toolkit/tree/master/packages/utils
  app.on('browser-window-created', (_, window) => {
    optimizer.watchWindowShortcuts(window)
  })

  createWindow()

  app.on('activate', function () {
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app"s specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.

// * Custom Protocol Handler

app.on('ready', () => {
  protocol.registerBufferProtocol('myApp', (request, callback) => {
    console.log(request)
    console.log(callback)
  })
})
```

and my element in the website look like this:

```
<div className="App-Lauch-Button">

    <Link to={'myApp://launch?param1=value1&param2=value2'} >

        <MdOpenInNew />

    </Link>

</div>
```

When i click the button the console display the next error:

```
Failed to launch 'myApp://launch?param1=value1&param2=value2' because the scheme does not have a registered handler
```

Also I don´t know how to test this in the development env, do i need to compile and install my app to test this?

What am i doing wrong?

BTW in the electron API documentation says that "protocol.registerBufferProtocol" is obsolete.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create my own URL protocol? (e.g. so://...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so)

Comment: "BTW in the electron API documentation says that "protocol.registerBufferProtocol" is obsolete." Then why do you use it?

Comment: "I ask to ChatGPT and it answered me that" That's exactly why i am asking for help

Comment: @jsejcksn Thanks I think that this will put me in the right direction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to launch my electron app from a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53530726/how-to-launch-my-electron-app-from-a-website)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achive this you must convert the mainWindow const into a global variable, set the DefaultProtocolClient and then use app.on 'second-instance' to handle the protocol

Code Example

```
if (process.defaultApp) {
  if (process.argv.length >= 2) {
    app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient('myApp', process.execPath, [path.resolve(process.argv[1])])
  } else {
    app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient('myApp')
  }
}

let mainWindow

function createWindow()...

// * Linux & MacOS handler

app.on('open-url', (_event, url) => {
  dialog.showErrorBox('Welcome back', 'coming from: ' + url)
})

// * Windows Handler

const getTheLock = app.requestSingleInstanceLock()

if (getTheLock === false) {
  app.quit()
} else {
  app.on('second-instance', (event, commandLine, workingDirectory) => {
    if (mainWindow) {
      if (mainWindow.isMinimized()) mainWindow.restore()
      mainWindow.focus()
    }
  })
}
```

Reference from Electron Documentation!

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/launch-app-from-url-in-another-app