# How to launch an app by external request from a chrome c#

Tags: c#, windows, google-chrome

I have a problem. When I try launch my installed app by external request from a chrome browser. Browser copies the app to

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\43.0.2357.130

and run it from there. It is bad because my programm makes a file and the file can't be read...

> Access to the path 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\43.0.2357.130\lp.pat' is denied.

For example I launch my app by link "myapp://Tag". The "myapp" it's a key in the registry. The "Tag" it's a argument for the command line.

How to make that application to be started from its own directory?

Comment: you can't run applications from a browser. think of what would happen if websites could run applications on the computer they are being viewed from.

Comment: Why? I added in the registry a key and by the key I launch my app. For example: myapp://TAG. The tag is sending as parameter in the command line.

Comment: a similar question was asked a few days ago http://stackoverflow.com/a/31003781/1666620

Comment: Sure it's copied there and it's not its  **working directory**? I'd presume Chrome won't pollute his own folder...

Comment: No, when I'm using the Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() function, it return that directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\43.0.2357.130, but my program directory is the C:\myprogram\

Comment: Exactly. Working directory is one thing. Installation directory is another. Your program stays in his own directory but it's working directory is chrome one. You can run winword from OpenOffice directory...

Comment: Thank you for explanation of the problem! My problem is solved by using a Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location instead of Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() for making the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved by using a Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location instead of Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() for making the file.

---

Thanks to Adriano Repetti.