# Detect and launch .exe file on local machine from MVC web page

Tags: c#, winforms, model-view-controller, browser

I am trying to achieve similar to [this](https://www.roblox.com/games/412192008/McDonalds-Tycoon-UPDATES) When the 'Play' button is clicked, it detect whether 'Roblox' application is installed on client machine or not. If it is not installed, it prompt the user to download and install it.
I have my web application build in MVC C# and a WinForm Application(.exe) C#. I am trying to launch .exe when a button is clicked on the web page in browser. If the .exe is not installed, prompt the user to download and install the .exe. If it is already installed, then launch it. I have followed [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31003412/launch-an-exe-from-browser-windows?lq=1) steps, but did not understand how to check if .exe is already installed on client machine or not. Do I have to create a browser Plugin or Extension to achieve this.
Please advice.

Comment: Search for "Magnet Links" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_URI_scheme

Comment: No, that did not help me

Answer (score 0):

So, after 1 week hunting over the internet, I found the solution.

From Google Chrome -

1. Create an extension using native messaging like [here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/nativeMessaging) (skip the
       registry part in this step). This extension will be used to send message to the 
       registry.
2. If you haven't published the extension on Google Chrome store, then
   on the web page, use chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage to check
   whether the extension is installed or not. If you get positive
   response, it means extension is already installed.
3. If the extension is published, see [here](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation?csw=1) how to detect and
   launch extension in google chrome
4. Create your desired .exe and a setup. Make sure to create registry values while 
   developing setup project. (see [here](http://www.codeease.com/add-registry-key-and-value-into-a-setup-project.html)) Registry value will have the path to .exe
5. Finally, when the extension is launched, it looks for registry
   values and .exe path in the registry and the .exe is launches.

For Mozilla Firefox -
  Create Firefox native messaging extension and follow the same steps above.

Hope this helps to my friends. Cheers!!!