# How to get Haskell script to load when a web page loads

Tags: haskell, euterpea

I am super new to Haskell and I am trying to learn it by build a web music project.

I successfully installed Euterpea and got the MIDI set up. I wrote a super basic script that imports Euterpea and plays a note.

I now want to put my script onto my hosted site and have it -- for starters -- automatically run when the page is loaded.

How would I start doing this? Do I need to have a Javascript that calls the Haskell script?

And how do I configure a web-based MIDI to interact with my script?

Comment: It sounds like there's some confusion here about how the web works broadly. Can you be a little more specific about what you want to do? You want to be able to load a web page and hear a note play from your browser?

Comment: You'd probably be better off not using Haskell for front-end web development.

Comment: As @AJFarmar said, Haskell isn't the best language for this sort of thing, but if you do want to use it then the [threepenny-gui](https://wiki.haskell.org/Threepenny-gui) library is a very nice place to start

Comment: @jberryman - yes, for starters I want the note to be played upon page load.  I have broader ambitions, but that's my MVP.

Comment: load Haskell script equivalent to lunch `executed file` from browser, it may be a complex thing, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31003412/launch-an-exe-from-browser-windows