# run exe file from react js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am totally new to React Js. I want to open a windows application / .exe file with the click of the web component. For e.g open whatapp.exe when we click on the button component from the web page created in react js. I found some other links but am not sure how to apply those solutions or they are relevant or not.

E.g:

[Execute an exe file using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19762350/execute-an-exe-file-using-node-js)

[How to execute an external program from within Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775088/how-to-execute-an-external-program-from-within-node-js)

Is my question is correct? can we do it like this or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Launch an exe from browser (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31003412/launch-an-exe-from-browser-windows)