# How to print a page content (div, form, jqgrid) using a single button click?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

i.e. When I click the button from my page, the desired page content should get printed in a sheet. The main goal over here is, it should not show me with the print dialog box/print preview of the page asking for OK or CANCEL button where we can also choose for multiple prints of a particular page. Thanks in advance.

Comment: DUPLICATE [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105674/how-can-i-prevent-the-user-from-printing-multiple-copies-of-a-html-page][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105674/how-can-i-prevent-the-user-from-printing-multiple-copies-of-a-html-page

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 0):

What is the browser you are targeting? There are some browser specific ways of doing this.

For IE :

```
<script language='VBScript'>
Sub Print()
       OLECMDID_PRINT = 6
       OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2
       OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER = 1
       call WB.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER,1)
End Sub
document.write "<object ID='WB' WIDTH=0 HEIGHT=0 CLASSID='CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2'></object> 
</script>




window.print();
```

Ref : [msdn blog](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/86eaeda9-c868-4d20-95b8-3b9bc2e19cc6/)

Comment: This should be the comment, not the answer.

Comment: Am targeting for Mozilla, Chrome & IE. Thanks.

Comment: @Ravinder Singh , yah I meant to add a comment, my mistake. Anyway now I made it an answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Create a print.js file by this code :

```
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------

(function($) {
    var opt;

    $.fn.jqprint = function (options) {
        opt = $.extend({}, $.fn.jqprint.defaults, options);

        var $element = (this instanceof jQuery) ? this : $(this);

        if (opt.operaSupport && $.browser.opera) 
        { 
            var tab = window.open("","jqPrint-preview");
            tab.document.open();

            var doc = tab.document;
        }
        else 
        {
            var $iframe = $("");

            if (!opt.debug) { $iframe.css({ position: "absolute", width: "0px", height: "0px", left: "-600px", top: "-600px" }); }

            $iframe.appendTo("body");
            var doc = $iframe[0].contentWindow.document;
        }

        if (opt.importCSS)
        {
            if ($("link[media=print]").length > 0) 
            {
                $("link[media=print]").each( function() {
                    doc.write("");
                });
            }
            else 
            {
                $("link").each( function() {
                    doc.write("");
                });
            }
        }

        if (opt.printContainer) { doc.write($element.outer()); }
        else { $element.each( function() { doc.write($(this).html()); }); }

        doc.close();

        (opt.operaSupport && $.browser.opera ? tab : $iframe[0].contentWindow).focus();
        setTimeout( function() { (opt.operaSupport && $.browser.opera ? tab : $iframe[0].contentWindow).print(); if (tab) { tab.close(); } }, 1000);
    }

    $.fn.jqprint.defaults = {
        debug: false,
        importCSS: true, 
        printContainer: true,
        operaSupport: true
    };

    // Thanks to 9__, found at http://users.livejournal.com/9__/380664.html
    jQuery.fn.outer = function() {
      return $($('').html(this.clone())).html();
    } 
})(jQuery);
```

And then include your print.js on an html page and see the demo of this :

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#printBtn").click(function(){
    jQuery("#print").jqprint();
    });
});
</script>
<input type="button" id="printBtn" value="Print" />
<div id="print">
This will print this content.
</div>
```

Comment: I tried implementing it, but it didn't work out. When I click on the button there is no action.