# Printing with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing

I need to write a Chrome extension that has a lot of Google Cloud Printing's functions, except that I will be sending my browser requests from my own application. To begin with, I need to do two things:

1) GCP has found some way to detect all *registered* printers on a computer (not necessarily all *connected* printers); how does it do that?

2) I need to send the print request directly to the printer without any settings, so window.print() is not an option (since it asks the user to input settings). How can I do this via JavaScript?

Does anyone have any idea..?

Yours,
Rei

Answer (score 1):

1. It isn't a matter of "detecting" a printer when Google has already been told about it. The printer will have already been registered — at that point Google has stored all of the data on the cloud.
2. No browsers will let you print without prompting, period. That's by design.

Comment: This is actually untrue, I found how to workaround Firefox to enable printing using their innate configs.

Answer (score 1):

1. According to [this](http://www.google.com/landing/cloudprint/win-enable.html), for classics printers, you need to enable Google Cloud Printing connector in windows, which means that GCP don't detect your printers, it just detect what windows tells you have installed or using a Cloud Ready printer that connect to the internet (and print from the internet) without PC.
2. [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9213943/792066), summary it says "no", for obvious security reasons.

I recommend you to read the [Help Page](https://support.google.com/cloudprint/?hl=en), since there is some misconception about what Cloud Print can and cannot do.