# How to print a page in web browser without asking confirmation?

Tags: javascript, html

Can I print a page by single button click without any prompt or dialog box of browser ?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213660/html-javascript-one-click-print-no-dialogs

Comment: ok thank you..but I need all browsers ,at least Chrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. That would be a huge security hole, as any script can click a button. It would make it possible to print millions of pages by just entering a webpage