# C# print html document from html string

Tags: c#, html, winforms

```
string s="<html><body>..some html code..</body></html>";
```

How to print document without `PrintDialog`?

> Output: ...some html code...

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML / Javascript One Click Print (no dialogs)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213660/html-javascript-one-click-print-no-dialogs)

Comment: ASP.NET? Winforms? Wpf?

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking, what do you mean by print?

Comment: To print from a printer

Comment: did you see that? (Edit:Edit:WinForm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understood you correctly, you need [WebBrowser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

```
WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
void Print(string str)
{
   webBrowser.DocumentText = str;
   webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser_DocumentCompleted;
}
void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   webBrowser.Print();
}
```

Comment: this will popup the print dialog.