# Print Html string in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, printdocument

I have a string variable which contains the source code of a HTML page. I have print this HTML page rendered view using source code string.

I should to print content in a single click and specify few settings like PRINTER NAME, PAGE SIZE, MARGIN and ORIENTATION in the code without showing a dialog

I am trying to print it using C# PrintDocument and WebBrowser control of Windows Form application.

**First using WebBrowser**
WebBrowser is printing properly but I am not able set Printer Settings and PageSettings like PrinterName, Marging, Printing content height & width.

**Second: PrintDocument**
PrintDocumet provide better way for printer settings and page settings but it is print html source code as string not render html view.

The Problem Is

How to print HTML View of give html strings with specifying few settings like PRINTER NAME, PAGE SIZE and MARGIN (Solution should be free)

Comment: i think it was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197373/c-sharp-print-html-document-from-html-string

Comment: [How to print WebBrowser control content without showing print dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57233157/7444103)

Comment: None of the proposed answers explain how to set the Margins, Size and Orientation without using a Print Dialog.

Comment: Then set and configure the Default printer beforehand? Then set it back to what it was, eventually.

Comment: Consider a nuget package like [Aspose](https://nugetmusthaves.com/Package/Aspose.Html)

Comment: Aspose is not a free solution