# Jquery/JS to print the current document without print dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried working on the following lines:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('input').attr('readonly', true);
  window.open("", "_self");
  window.print();
  window.close();
});
```

The above code enables to open the print dialog but prompts the user to click Print.

**I have researched quite a bit on it and the nearest i got was a vb script which achieves the same.**

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That VB script solution works only in IE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213660/html-javascript-one-click-print-no-dialogs
There is no way of doing this for security reasons

Comment: But i suppose its definitely achievable using some tweaks and hacks. There is nothing in the web system that cannot be automated :P

Comment: Haha that's where you are wrong: Javascript runs very sandboxed and you can't bypass any security checks like these. Browsers are supposed to be safe you know

Comment: True that.. but consider a scenario where you have loads of documents like bank transcripts that need the print to be automated as and when the code encounters a print?

Comment: Then use for example C#'s `WebBrowser Class` basically building your own minibrowser (It sounds like a lot of work, but it isn't using this class). Javascript just isn't fit for what you try to do.

Comment: That does sound like stretching a leg, but definitely worth a try.