# Java Web App - Hiding Print Dialog when printing

Tags: java, printing, zebra-printers

Is it feasible to hide the print dialog when printing something via a web-based application?

I do realize the security issues around this i.e. What if websites start printing "spam" directly into your printer etc...

I've also seen extensions out there for specific browsers that might disable this option as a form of a hack. I'm just wondering if this technically feasible? Is it any form or way do-able programatically?

My application will end up printing labels and our users would need to print some info on labels when performing these actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible. Like you already mentioned it would be a security issue.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32253234/1405363 for a basic instruction how to implement an own application to solve the problem.

There a also some ready-to-use solutions which require an additional installation. [QZ Tray](https://github.com/qzind/tray) (a cross-platform and cross-browser plugin) is one of them.