# How can I bypass print preview from a Google Apps Script Web App?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, google-chrome-app, kiosk-mode

I am creating a Google Apps Script Web App where I want to automatically print labels when a user submits information via a Submit button (whilst also recording the information).  I can display the  label as a html webpage and use window.print() to send it to the printer but this brings up the print preview dialog. Given that:

1. I want to be able to run the Web App on a Chrome device (i.e. chromebook or chromebox) and
2. I will probably set the device up in Kiosk Mode using Chrome Sign Builder so that the App is the only thing a user can use on that device.

...is there a way to bypass the print preview dialog so that the label goes straight to the default printer (a label printer)?

Answer (score 1):

[Window.print()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print) is part of the [Window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) [Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) and does not belong to the Google Apps Script environment.

In short, you cannot modify the parameters of the `window.print()` method or bypass them from javascript. You can [modify the parameter in your browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54088862) to automate the process or build a [back-end connected to the printer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32253234) that
allows the user print directly