# When we click on print, the popup does not come in it, it gets printed directly

Tags: javascript, printing, printing-web-page

When we click on print, the popup does not come in it, it gets printed directly. How can this be done in codeigniter?

We have a p.o.s, in that we need such that when we print an order, popup should not appear in it for print. Print as soon as you click on the print button. (whichever machine is connected)
How to do this in codigniter? please help

Comment: It's not related to `codeigniter` or `php` it's more related to `JS` or maybe it's because of printer setting, Please share your code

Comment: And also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: there's no way to control the print dialog on the browser because it depends on the browser. But there are some tricks to overcome the problem .. you might have some inspiration here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213660/html-javascript-one-click-print-no-dialogs like how to set up a custom schema that will run a third party stuff via url or how to config firefox to print silent