# Open a folder in finder/explorer from a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, silverlight, flash

If I have a file system path can I open a window in Explorer (on windows) or in Finder (on OS X) displaying the folder that the path leads to?

Cookie points for answers that are cross-platform and/or plugin-less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be able to run a new process from a browser.  There are a few ways to do this.  I'll show the JNLP way to do this.

Create a jnlp file as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://example/" href="jnlpTest.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Some Title</title>
        <vendor>Some Vendor</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://example/" />
        <description>Some Description</description>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.6+" />
        <jar href="jnlpTest.jar" />
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="MainClass" />
</jnlp>
```

Create a jnlpTest.jar from the following:

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            //TODO - different exec for Mac
            rt.exec("explorer.exe");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //exception
        }

    }
}
```

With a Manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: MainClass
```

Sign your JNLP jar:

```
keytool -genkey -keystore testKeys -alias jdc
jarsigner -keystore testKeys jnlpTest.jar jdc
```

place both the jar and jnlp file on a web server.  Make sure the mime type JNLP is served as `application/x-java-jnlp-file`.

Reference for making a JNLP: http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-web-start-jnlp-hello

Now when a user clicks your jnlp link they will download the jar and be asked if it is ok to run.  Running it will cause the explorer window to open.  I know it's not the best solution, but any solution will require asking the users permission to execute code on their machine.

Comment: Something this vague should really be a comment, not an answer. I'd also be very very surprised if the Mac port of Silverlight includes COM.

Comment: I started putting this in a comment, but I did want to add a little more information than just "try this url".  Here is a starting point if that helps, if not ignore my answer.

Comment: @DMoses The linked article says in the beginning: "It should be noted that these features are only available in elevated privileges Out-Of-Browser mode and are not available in-browser." Are you absolutely relevant to this question?

Comment: Well, the edit is less vague, but it looks like you're misunderstanding what the OP wants. I believe it's not "how to read a file on the filesystem", but "how to open a file manager window"

Comment: Ahh in that case i'll change my answer appropriatly.

Comment: If you are going down that path, on OS X, you probably want to use `open`. So, instead of explorer.exe, `open ~/Documents/` or whatever.

Comment: I've tried this with a more recent example (below) and I found it was blocked.  I don't manage the security settings so there  may be a way around it if you have control (?) but I think not after Java 8 update 20 (according to the message).  Worth checking before anyone gets too involved with this solution.  For example, I'm not going to get an external cert for a little app to open windows explorer! (http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/web-start/java-web-start-getting-started/)

Answer (score 3):

For [node-webkit](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/References/Shell/) ([NW.js](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/References/Shell/)) users you can use...

```
var gui = require("nw.gui");

document.querySelector("[data-location]").onclick = function() {
  gui.Shell.showItemInFolder(__dirname + '/content/project/' + this.textContent);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably what you are looking for is registering your own custom protocol in the OS that will handle links such as `mycustomapp://path=/mypath&extra=42` and then let the browser delegate link clicks to your app which would then trigger the appropriate action depending on the OS, i.e. for macos you would run `open -R /mypath` to reveal in Finder, for windows run `explorer.exe /e,/mypath` and for android/ios trigger the corresponding intent actions.

This is the approach that for example zoom, webex, telegram, reddit and other apps are using.

#### MacOS

For [macos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471581/how-to-map-a-custom-protocol-to-an-application-on-the-mac) you'll need something like this in your `Info.plist` file:

```xml
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.myapp.content</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>mycustomapp</string>
            <string>mycustomapp_v2</string>
            <string>mycustomapp_v3</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

#### Windows

On windows you'll need to add a [new handler to the registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows).

#### Android & iOS

For android and iOS see:

- [Android / iOS - Custom URI / Protocol Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421048/android-ios-custom-uri-protocol-handling)