# How to extend URL class to support other protocols in java (android)?

Tags: java, android, url, url-encoding

I want to url encode a string that has an unsupported url protocol(scheme).
So, on the 3rd line, an exception will be thrown. Is there anyway to make URL class support "mmsh" or any other "custom_name" scheme?

EDIT: I do not want to register some protocols for my application. I just want to be able to use URL class without "unsupported protocol" exception. I am using URL class just to parse and tidy the url string.

```
String string="mmsh://myserver.com/abc";

String decodedURL = URLDecoder.decode(string, "UTF-8");
URL url = new URL(decodedURL);
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
```

Comment: In java you need to extend from [URLStreamHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLStreamHandler.html) check example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861500/url-to-load-resources-from-the-classpath-in-java)

Comment: This might be of some help try : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421048/android-ios-custom-uri-protocol-handling

Comment: Thank you all, but I do not want to register some protocols for my application. I just want to be able to use URL class without "unsupported protocol" exception. I am using URL class just to parse and tidy the url string.

Answer (score 2):

I created sample program based on the code provided on   [`URL to load resources from the classpath in Java`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861500/url-to-load-resources-from-the-classpath-in-java)   and [`Custom URL protocols and multiple classloaders`](https://web.archive.org/web/20150507125111/http://www.cooljeff.co.uk:80/2009/12/12/custom-url-protocols-and-multiple-classloaders/) and it seems to work fine.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    URL url;
    try {

        url = new URL(null, "user:text.xml", new Handler());
        InputStream ins = url.openStream();
        ins.read();
        Log.d("CustomURL", "Created and accessed it using custom handler ");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
public static class Handler extends URLStreamHandler {
    @Override
    protected URLConnection openConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
        return new UserURLConnection(url);
    }

    public Handler() {
    }

    private static class UserURLConnection extends URLConnection {
        private String fileName;
        public UserURLConnection(URL url) {
            super(url);
            fileName = url.getPath();
        }
        @Override
        public void connect() throws IOException {
        }
        @Override
        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {

            File absolutePath = new File("/data/local/", fileName);
            return new FileInputStream(absolutePath);
        }
    }
}
```