# Phonegap - Open app from webpage and trigger function (IOS)

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova

Is it possible top open a Phonegap IOS app from a webpage link - and then trigger a function within the app?

I know its possible to open native apps from a web page - but i'm struggling to find any info / plugins that will point me in the right direction to do this with a HTML5 Phonegap app.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use protocol handlers to trigger an app launch in IOS, and, triggering a function from JS is definitely possible.  With the right URL scheme, you could send a message to the phonegap page that a js event needs to be triggered.  Using that JS event, you can trigger an obj-c function.

Protocol Handlers:
[Android / iOS - Custom URI / Protocol Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421048/android-ios-custom-uri-protocol-handling)

Triggering obj-c function from JS:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide

Comment: looks like a good fit - thanks for your help - i'll check it out