# Google + local App Interface with a Responsive Web App

Tags: local, google-plus

I am developing a responsive web app which will output links to different businesses' https://plus.google.com/app/basic/local  pages.  For users accessing these output links with their smart phone, I want them to be able view the businesses plus.google.com pages using the google + local app.

From my initial experiments, it appears that some smart devices will give the user an option of viewing the pages in either a browser page or with the google + local app.  However, I cannot determine why some smart devices give the user the option and others do not.

In the tests, each smart phone had the google + local app installed.  We experimented with being logged into google and not being logged in.  It did not seem to make a difference either way.

Can someone explain to me what I need to do so that every smart device will give the user the option to view the pages with the google + local app?

Is there a snippet of code that is needed in order to have the web app ping the smart device to look to see if the google + local app is installed?  If so, what is needed? And what is needed to then give the user the option of viewing the page in either an browser page or through the google + local app.

I want the system to work equally well on all smart phone platforms: Android, Apple & Windows.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Apps can be configured to respond to given URL patterns. Users on most platforms can also choose to make a given app the default for an address. For some information on how developers do this, see [this stack overflow post about iOS and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421048/android-ios-custom-uri-protocol-handling). I'm sure Windows phones have similar capabilities.

My guess is that the differences that you witnessed are due to different phone configurations.