# Open link in browser inside iOS app with web techniques

Tags: ios, web, hyperlink

Let's assume someone is running a web app directly inside a simple iOS app with UIWebView.
It it possible to open a external website link inside the browser (Safari Mobile) with web techniques like JavaScript? If yes, how could it be done?

Comment: Use an `iFrame` perhaps?

Comment: No possibility due many different websites should be able to be load and most websites block inlining into an iframe.

Answer (score 2):

To open a URL programmatically:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.google.com"];
```

As far as your WebView, you can use your WebViewDelegate to catch and inspect any hyperlinks the user selects.  For example:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *urlPath = [request URL];
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
    {
        if ([[urlPath scheme] hasPrefix:@"http"]))
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlPath];
            return (NO);
        }

    }

    return (YES);
}
```

This should open any hyperlink click in browser app.

You can also create a custom protocol, see [Android / iOS - Custom URI / Protocol Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421048/android-ios-custom-uri-protocol-handling/11421251#11421251), and catch those in this same delegate handler by checking the [url scheme] property.  This will allow you to explicitly do something with javascript.