# mobile app, redirec from browser to app on the phone

Tags: android, html, redirect, mobile

I have a question.
I have to make link/button in html which will contain number. If user clicked on this button/link he should be redirected to panel/views where we type the phone number.

Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

- You need to have a Protocol Handler. Lets say something like
  `Pawel://` or any other. The URL should be triggered when you click the Button on
  the web page in the mobile device.
- In the `AndroidManifest` of your app you have to register this
  protocol handler. This tells android    that your app is capable of
  handling that protocol handler. If your    is the only app installed
  at the user that can handle this protocol    handler, then clicking
  of the button will open the app(your desired    activity)
  automatically. Otherwise it will ask user to choose amongst    the
  available option.
- Along with this custom protocol handler, you can attach a parameter
  containing the number. This parameter can be parsed in the app(inside `onCreate`, when
  it receives this url in the activity with the intent.
- After parsing you can set it in TextView.

You might want to check [Android / iOS - Custom URI / Protocol Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421048/android-ios-custom-uri-protocol-handling) if still working on it.

Comment: Thanks, I will try. Do you know how do this in iOS and winphone also?