# Initiate call automatically using tel in Href

Tags: php, asp.net, html, tel

I am trying to call via Html.I have tried this
`<a href='+2000000200200'>Please Click to Call</a>`

Now when I click on this , it *opens the the dialer having this number and then I press call and it initiates the call.*
Now the thing I am trying to do is **When I click the link , it automatically initiate the call**.I mean the step of Dialler open and pressing call must be skip.So whenever I click the link it should start making call
Is it possible to do like this?I Really need experts advice about this
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a [custom protocol handler](http://cstruter.com/blog/279) for this type of thing, but the handler obviously needs to be installed on the machine using it.

Check [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421048/android-ios-custom-uri-protocol-handling) for custom protocol handling in ios and android.

**Custom protocol handling windows**

Using C#, register registry keys:

```
RegistryKey Key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey("test");
Key.CreateSubKey("DefaultIcon").SetValue("", "caller.exe,1");
Key.SetValue("", "call:Protocol");
Key.SetValue("URL Protocol", "");
Key.CreateSubKey(@"shell\open\command").SetValue("", "caller.exe %1");
```

Caller.exe being your handler:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // args[0] contains the phone number
    }
}
```

Finally:

```
<a href="call:2000000200200">Call Number</a>
```

Comment: but it wont work on Android or Iphone? right? It will work on only windows phone?

Comment: Check this thread out as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421048/android-ios-custom-uri-protocol-handling

Comment: ok but it seems that just to provide this functionality , we need to build a App first , install it on users machine/mobile and then it will behave like our requirements. Doesn't sound logical for me.

Comment: Yup, exactly, you will have to build an app that handles it etc

Comment: ok , but one last thing.I only have to visit him my web site and just for this I ask him to first install this app and after then visit my web site? isn't it ironic?

Comment: Lol, unfortunately if you want someone to make calls via a link (like your requirement) this is the route you will have to take.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry is not possible and is inteend to be that way. Making the call needs a 3rd application and ofc you wouldnt want anyone making calls or even by mistake a call being made by just clicking.

Comment: ok thanks for the answer but I want to know WHY?
is it some sort of TEL protocol limitation or OS limitation or what?

Comment: It's not a question of the TEL protocol, it's a question of how the client browser / client device choses to handle such events. You cannot override OS behaviour just by writing different code on your website. If you could, it would be a major security problem.