# What does the new BCH regex mean?

Tags: regex, bitcoin, coinbase-api, cryptocurrency, segwit

BCH regex was recently updated (in the API) to: `"address_regex": "^([13][a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{25,34})|^((bitcoincash:)?(q|p)[a-z0-9]{41})|^((BITCOINCASH:)?(Q|P)[A-Z0-9]{41})$"`

Is this a Segwit thing?

I understand it's now saying addresses may start with "bitcoincash:" or "BITCOINCASH:", but that's a thing, or is it some internal Coinbase designation?

Comment: The upper-case variant allows fore more efficient QR encoding

Answer (score 9):

Breaking down this regex, there are three possible that constitute a valid BCH address:

## 1st Alternative `^([13][a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{25,34})`:

- Starts with either a `1` or a `3`
- Follows this with between 25 and 34 alphanumeric characters **excluding** `l`, `I`, `O` and `0`

## 2nd Alternative `^((bitcoincash:)?(q|p)[a-z0-9]{41})`:

- Starts with the literal string `bitcoincash:` (strangely this can occur more than once)
- Follows this with either a `q` or a `p`
- Follows this with exactly 41 alphanumeric characters (only in lowercase)

## 3rd Alternative `^((BITCOINCASH:)?(Q|P)[A-Z0-9]{41})$`:

- Starts with the literal string `BITCOINCASH:` (strangely this can occur more than once)
- Follows this with either a `Q` or a `P`
- Follows this with exactly 41 alphanumeric characters (only in uppercase)

Essentially, Coinbase is now simply accepting the three above regexes as valid BCH addresses, adding `bitcoincash` as a recognised protocol used by BCH.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the regex, but I suppose my question should have been clearer and it's addressed a bit in your last sentence: When did these new address formats (Q|P) and bitcoincash: prefix come in to play?

Comment: The API would simply implement custom protocol handling, which is covered in depth in [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421048/android-ios-custom-uri-protocol-handling). The final component of your question regarding *when* they came into play would be a question for the [**Bitcoin StackExchange**](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I didn't get your comment "_strangely this can occur more than once_".
`(bitcoincash:)?` - This means "_bitcoincash:_" is optional and may be present or may be missing, but if present it will occur only once.

Answer (score -1):

let me break it down for you
so there are three regex in it, as after new additions now all three are accepted as valid BCH addresses now

```
/^([13]{1}[a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{33}|(bitcoincash:)?(q|p)[a-z0-9]{41}|(BITCOINCASH:)?(Q|P)[A-Z0-9]{41})$/
```

Breaking it down

First type of addresses

```
[13]{1}
```

address will start with L, M or 3, {1} defines that only match one character in square bracket

```
/[13]{1}[a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]/
```

cannot have l (small el), I (capital eye), O (capital O) and 0 (zero)

```
/[13]{1}[a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{26,33}/
```

can be 27 to 34 characters long, remember we already checked the first character to be 1 or 3, so remaining address will be 26 to 33 characters long

second type of address

```
bitcoincash:
```

will start with bitcoincash:

```
(bitcoincash:)?(q|p)
```

followed by q or p

```
(bitcoincash:)?(q|p)[a-z0-9]
```

can only have lower case letters and numbers

```
(bitcoincash:)?(q|p)[a-z0-9]{41}
```

will be 54 characters long, we already checked first 11 characters to be bitcoincash: followed by another character to be Q or p, so remaining address will be 41 characters long

third type of address

```
BITCOINCASH:
```

will start with BITCOINCASH:

```
(BITCOINCASH:)?(Q|P)
```

followed by Q or P

```
(BITCOINCASH:)?(Q|P)[a-z0-9]
```

can only have lower case letters and numbers

```
(BITCOINCASH:)?(Q|P)[a-z0-9]{41}
```

will be 54 characters long, we already checked first 11 characters to be BITCOINCASH: followed by another character to be Q or P, so remaining address will be 41 characters long