# Running a Mac Application from a custom URL protocol

Tags: web-applications, url-protocol

I am trying to create an idiot-proof method of activating an application I built in Automator. The application essentially takes images, crops them to 4x6 and sends them to a printer.

I am trying to create an html page (hosted locally) with a link that will run this application when clicked.

I've tried following the instructions provided here: [How to map a custom protocol to an application on the Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471581/how-to-map-a-custom-protocol-to-an-application-on-the-mac)

But I cannot get my head around how to complete this. I need to know how to get application "X" to run when visiting a custom URL.

I have virtually no experience with Applescript or any other programming language. Can anyone walk me through how to create a custom URL handler for this application?

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds to me like you are asking the same question again, but asking for more info. I think you should do that in the comments of the original question rather than creating a new one.