# how to make NSURL point to local dir?

Tags: cocoa, nsurlconnection, nsurlprotocol

reading Adium code today, found an interesting usage of NSURL:

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"adium://%@/adium", [messageStyle.bundle bundleIdentifier]]];
[[webView mainFrame] loadHTMLString:[messageStyle baseTemplateForChat:chat] baseURL:baseURL];
```

I tried to log the url and got this *adium://im.adium.Smooth Operator.style/adium*, Then I created a blank project to see how to create such an NSURL but failed. When I sending loadHTMLString message to a webview's frame in my project, if the baseURL is nil, everything is fine, if not, I got a blank page in the view.

here is my code, the project name is webkit

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"webkit://resource"];
//if baseURL is nil or [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL], everything is fine
[[webView mainFrame] loadHTMLString:@"<html><head></head><body><div>helloworld</div></body></html>" 
                     baseURL: baseURL];
[frameView setDocumentView:webView];
[[frameView documentView] setFrame:[frameView visibleRect]];
```

the question is how to make a self defined protocol instead of http://?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**adium://%@/adium** , first section is called protocol you can also register your protocol webkit:  Take a look at [How to map a custom protocol to an application on the Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471581/how-to-map-a-custom-protocol-to-an-application-on-the-mac) and [Launch Scripts from Webpage Links](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/linktrigger/)

Answer (score 0):

```
[NSURLProtocol registerClass:[AIAdiumURLProtocol class]];
[ESWebView registerURLSchemeAsLocal:@"adium"];
```

I tried to find where did adium define the adium schema in the info.plist, unfortunately, there's nothing there, only some irc/xmpp protocols.

so I finally launched the debugger, and found the code above in the AIWebKitDelegate init method, anyway this is another way to register a self defined protocol~