# Detect or check existing applications installed in PC

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am developing a website. In my website, I have created some applications and the buttons linked to those applications. Once the users click on the button, the users will be prompted to install the application.

**My question is:**

If the users had not installed the applications in their PC, so they will be prompted to install the applications in their PC once they click on the buttons; but if they had already installed the applications on their PC, the application should reject or alert the users that the same application is already installed.

So, how should I write the code to detect or to check the applications whether they had already been installed into the users'PC?

Comment: This is not possible from within a web site for obvious security reasons. You'd have to write a program that the user would have to download and execute (probably with admin privileges) that then could check for any applications installed.

Comment: For privacy and security reasons, it is unlikely that you will be able to do this with just JavaScript.  One way could be to create a browser plugin and to check for the existence of the plugin.  However, your users are probably nit interested in installing another browser plugin just for this purpose.

Comment: It's also possible just to use a Java applet, but in the end, it's all about whether or not the user trusts the application.

Comment: #Pekka , #Moshe , #remyabel : Thanks for the comments. I will find another way.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options

1. Mime Types

   On most browsers (not IE) you can see defined mime handlers, for example, application/foo.  You can then loop through [`navigator.mimeTypes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorPlugins.mimeTypes?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web/API/Navigator.mimeTypes), and see if it exists.  It's not an Array (strictly), so you need to convert it.

   ```
   var mimes = Array.prototype.slice.call(navigator.mimeTypes)
   if (mimes.length && mimes.indexOf("application/foo") !== -1) {
       // we've got it!
   }
   else {
       // we're on IE and/or the app isn't installed
   }
   ```
2. Extensions/Addons

   In addition to your app's normal behavior, it can install a very simple and small extension into the user's browser(s).  The extension would implement a content script, which is only active on your website, and replaces the Download button with a Run button.  Might be a bit of overkill, and annoy users.
3. Register a **custom://uri**

   A custom URI allows you to use this [neat trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14706422/1074592).  If your app isn't installed, it will fail to redirect, and downloadURL will be loaded.  For example, try changing appurl to `itunes://foobar`, if you have iTunes installed.

   ```
   var appurl = 'myapp://launch';
   var downloadURL = '/installer.exe';

   var timeout;

   function preventPopup() {
       clearTimeout(timeout);
       timeout = null;
       window.removeEventListener('pagehide', preventPopup);
   }

   function startApp() {
       document.location = appurl;
       timeout = setTimeout(function () {
           location.href = downloadURL;
       }, 1000);
       window.addEventListener('pagehide', preventPopup);
   }

   startApp();
   ```

   This is probably the best solution.

   - [Registering an Application to a URI Scheme (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
   - [Creating custom URL handlers in Ubuntu 11.04, 11.10, GNOME 3.0](http://jarrpa.net/2011/10/28/creating-custom-url-handlers-in-ubuntu-11-04-11-10-gnome-3-0/)
   - [How to map a custom protocol to an application on the Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471581/how-to-map-a-custom-protocol-to-an-application-on-the-mac)

Comment: Thank you very much, I will test all these methods right away.