# Handling opening of files and URLs in Python application packaged by PyInstaller

Tags: python, url, protocol-handler

Say I have developed an application `Awesome` and deployed it onto a user machine with an artefact made with PyInstaller. Let's just consider the Mac OS X artefact for now, `Awesome.app`.

During the installation process, `Awesome.app` is registered to open files of type `*.awesome` and to handle URLs of the form `awesome://*` (i.e. handle the custom protocol `awesome`).

The user runs an instance of `Awesome.app`. For the sakes of argument let's say it has process id `1234`.
Then, the user opens a file `foo.awesome`.

How can I ensure that this open event is handled by the already-running `Awesome` process 1234? What code path actually taken for this to happen within the Python application?

If the answer is platform-specific I'd still like to hear about each of Windows, Mac OS X and Ubuntu.

Comment: I found that the best answer to doing this on Mac can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471581/how-to-map-a-custom-protocol-to-an-application-on-the-mac

Comment: This of course does not answer the question. I'm just confused about what code path is taken to communicate with the running process that it needs to open a file.

Comment: Did you found out the answer.