# How to get header values from browser in Swing Application?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have one URL lets say (www.example.com). When I hit this URL using below code it will be opened in system default browser.In the browser it will ask user to enter username and password . Then he has to enter username and password. If they are correct again the page will be redirected to (www.example.com).Now i have to get header value "isSuccess" form the browser.If it is normal web application i can achieve it using "`request.getHeader("isSuccess")`". But How can I achieve the same in Swing Application?

```
//Swing code to open URL in default browser
Desktop d=Desktop.getDesktop();
d.browse(new URI("http://www.example.com"));
```

Note : Due to security reasons I used dummy URLs above.

Comment: You cannot get the header value using this approach. The control is passed to the native default browser once you execute `d.browse(..` and from then your program isn't control of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it using `Desktop`.  All `Desktop.browse()` does is tell the default browser to open a URL.  Just as if you navigated to a certain URL in your favorite browser, it doesn't display the HTTP header information for you to see.

Two options.  First using a browser inside of you Swing applications, such as with this: http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/index.html

Second, using a custom protocol.  In this case a web page, such as your success page, can send a message to an installed application.  You'll have to have a different solution per platform though ([OS X JRE 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471581/how-to-map-a-custom-protocol-to-an-application-on-the-mac), [OS X JRE 7, look at documentation on how to add a custom protocol](https://bitbucket.org/infinitekind/appbundler), [Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you please let me know how to achieve this using http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/index.html