# How do you link to an external application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, macos

I've always been wondering about how to link to an application like Safari, Sublime, Settings, etc.. Some websites has a banner on top that says "Open in app" and then an 'Open' button, that opens the application by a script or something. I wan't to do the same thing but have no idea of how to do it. Let's have Safari as example, or Some other application in Mac. I would be really grateful if anyone could help me with that.

Have a nice day everyone! :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471581/how-to-map-a-custom-protocol-to-an-application-on-the-mac