# Associate scheme (eg. cms://) to a Windows program

Tags: windows, credentials

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [how do I create my own URL protocol? (e.g. so://…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so)
>   [How do I register a custom URL protocol in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows)

Is there a way to associate a scheme, like cms:// to a Windows program?

So when an user types cms://user:password@server.com, it opens the program and can automatically connect using the given credentials.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is covered in an MSDN article called [Registering an Application to a URL Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: Didn't knew it was that easy... Couldn't find it, because I was searching on scheme instead of protocol :S Thank you!

Comment: I probably wasn't the only one, since the MSDN article is renamed to 'Registering an Application to a URI Scheme' ;-)

Answer (score 1):

What you need to know to register an application to a URL Protocol:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(VS.85).aspx

Tells you the registry details and gives you a code sample.