# Open Office Communicator Session from C#

Tags: c#, sip, office-communicator

I am working on a WPF application and I wish to open sip:Username@company.com links. I am able to open mailto links using the following code:

```
private void btnSendEmail_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string mailURL = String.Format("mailto:{0}", UserDetails.EmailAddress);
        Process.Start(mailURL);
        Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        // Handle exception
    }
}
```

Although, I am unable to open sip: links in a similar way. What I am trying to achieve is to open a new chat session with a user, like I am able to do when I follow sip: links from Outlook.

Any ideas?

**Edit:** I ended up using the CommunicatorAPI. Messenger.InstantMessage() seems to work for me. More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787232.aspx

Comment: Good to see that you got it working. Since you managed to solve your problem, you should post your solution as an answer instead of editing so we can upvote and recognize it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the CommunicatorAPI. Messenger.InstantMessage() seems to work for me. More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787232.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Using `Process.Start` works fine on my system (with Microsoft Lync 2010, a newer version of Communicator):

```
void Main()
{
    Process.Start("sip:username@company.com");
}
```

Running the above code results in a new chat window opening.  The only exception is when I enter my own user name, in which it starts composing a new Outlook e-mail message to myself.  What happens when you use this (maybe also try omitting the following call to `Close`).

Comment: This for some reason doesn't work for me. This always opens a new outlook window, basically same as mailto.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to associate a program with the "sip" uri scheme. Try this: [how do I create my own URL protocol? (e.g. so://...)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/389204/639613)

Comment: that won't help the OP since he doesn't want to implement a uri handler BUT he wants just to use the existing `sip:` handler!

Comment: Maybe that's the problem: no "sip:" handler. That's what I wanted him to validate.

Comment: Perhaps, but it will still be a problem on other computers in my office network that will use this code. Unfortunately, most of them wont have admin access and therefore, no access to registry.

Answer (score 0):

if you have Lync or Office Communicator installed, they should respond appropriately to the sip: uri scheme. Also, tel:, callto: etc. For reference, the full list is [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398376.aspx).

Is this not working for you from a WPF app? Does it work for you from a basic html page?

Answer (score 0):

The following code probably didn't work for you because you were trying to IM yourself.

```
Process.Start("sip:username@company.com");
```