# Launching my Desktop application via the intent URI

Tags: c#, uri

How to create URI in my application - like spotify - and launch my application using the intent URI.

I need a solution to sends an email with a link in it that when clicked should launch my c# application.

Comment: I do it,but some my question don't have any answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I create my own URL protocol? (e.g. so://...)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows platforms you can use "Pluggable Protocols". See [Registering an Application to a URL Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible due to security reason. In windows when user click on link Operating System looks for process associated with uris (usualy browser).

If user use Internet Explorer you can think of using ActiveX.

EDIT:

Found something that may help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh779672.aspx

Comment: for example visit this link http://open.spotify.com/artist/5C43FNPZAzBXLGWgkYWbs1 or spotify:track:4f1FAi7NIPaCyeLTnvhOCC