# How to create a protocol for my application

Tags: c#, protocols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how do I create my own URL protocol? (e.g. so://…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so)

Is there any way to create a protocol for my application so `myapp://` can open my application from a browser like `skype://` and `magnet://` and `chrome://` do for Skype, utorrent and chrome?

Also can I create a run command so users can open my application directly through `start  > run > myapplication.exe`

I will create my application in C# and I think this will help my users to open the application easily is there any way to do it?

Here I used `myapp://` as an example to the protocol that I create and `myapplication.exe` as my program name.

Comment: I think that you could look at this previous SO question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so

Comment: but it don't answer for a run command

Comment: what prevents you from running your app.exe directly from the start/run dialog, once it has been put into the `%PATH%`?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx