# can chrome extension connect to backend application in the desktop

Tags: google-chrome, desktop-application

is there any way with chrome extension to get / set parameters with command line application in the desktop ? 
with out using npnpi ? maybe http?

Answer (score 0):

No there is not any feasible way to do it for security reasons. However you can register a custom protocol like `example://` and install a program on client system to handle your custom protocol. Hope this helps!

Comment: tnx,can you direct me to tutorial or link ? how this method called ( so i can goggle it )

Comment: For registering a custom protocol: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so`. After you have registered your own protocol, you need to write a desktop application that handles your protocol. Here is a link that might help you:`http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/df04292f-bfe0-44a9-a067-87121fa4a108`.