# Open Application from URL

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how do I create my own URL protocol? (e.g. so://…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so)

How could I go around typing into my browser, for example "assembly://update". And it passes the string "update" into the startup params of an application? I know steam does it, so I was wondering if it was possible though a registry tweak.

**Found it.** The answer that worked for me, is here: [how do I create my own URL protocol? (e.g. so://...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so)

Comment: It is called "pluggable protocol" - search for it... get your year  supply of food to read through and implement so.