# How do I launch custom application on client machine from Django web page

Tags: python, django

I am writing a Django based web application. Following is what I need to achieve

- Check if the custom application is already installed on the client machine (mostly Windows based)
- If the application is installed then launch the same from the web page
- If not installed, push the application to client machine from the web page for user to install (Done)
- Upon clicking on the stop button on webpage the application on client machine should stop

I am reading more about deeplink on web for same, however most of it is for mobile browsers and app is in mobile device

If anybody has done this, I would really appreciate if you share the design approach.

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30401026/launch-an-application-using-html/30401405 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so