# How do Spotify URI's work?

Tags: uri, spotify

Let's use Spotify for example. Let's say you take a Spotify URI, and you enter it in your browser, the Spotify client then begins playing music. What is this called? Is it easy to do? Do you have to inject anything into the browser/does it even require a webhelper of any sort? If so, how does the web helper pass this data on to the main program? I guess the biggest question I'm asking is the easiest way to have an app receive some data from the browser, like Spotify does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I create my own URL protocol? (e.g. so://...)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so)