# Open form with specific record displayed in Axapta 2009 by using an URL or command line

Tags: axapta, x++

Running Axapta 2009, you see selected company and form in a format similar to an URL. However, copying and pasting this format does not seem to navigate you to the form which you copied the format from.

I like to be able to open Axapta with a specific form and (when possible) specific record shown. Ideally using a real URL.

Is this possible without massive X++ without X++ or just little X++? If so, how?

Comment: I believe this question was answered a few days ago:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21315422/what-handles-dynamics-urls][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21315422/what-handles-dynamics-urls

Comment: Thank you @Klaas Deforche. To find people find it using Google: can you enter your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answer to this question:

[What handles dynamics:// URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21315422/what-handles-dynamics-urls/21316686#21316686)

It covers AX 2012, but aplies to AX 2009 as well, is my guess.