# AX 2012: How to get rid of the "Would you like to access a Dynamics client?" warning

Tags: named-pipes, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, axapta

When the link in an event notification email (drilldown link) is clicked this opens the form in the AX client.
This works as expected. However, there is the "Would you like to access a Dynamics client?" message which shows up every time.

Is there any way to get rid of this message?

Comment: Is a "drilldown link" a hyperlink from outside the application?!?

Comment: Yes, this the link AX sends in event notification emails.
There must be a better word for this...
I modified the question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way.  The drilldown URLs access "AxHLink.exe", which appears to be creating the message.  You would have to create your own handler to get rid of the message.

See my question here for more info: 
[What handles dynamics:// URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21315422/what-handles-dynamics-urls)

Comment: Yes, it's a combination between AxHlink.exe and Microsoft.Dynamics.HLink.dll. If I'm to re-write this, I would like to be able to write to the named pipe running on a remote machine. Do you know if this is possible? I don't seem to find anything useful online.

Comment: If you rewrite it to handle a named pipe, I think you'll need to have your handler on every client with a registry key to handle your own custom `Dynamics://` urls, or `Dynamics2://` or whatever.  Doesn't seem practical.  You can look at Jan's solution he posted on that other stack question.