# Open direct links to AX-objects or datasets from external application

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

Is there a way to open a specified document, eg "production order 123" or form, eg "purchase orders" in Ax2012 from an external application directly?

In detail, I'm looking for something similiar like [AXPath](http://www.axaptapedia.com/AxPath), but this doesn't work with versions greater then 2009.

Is there any ( maybe included ) way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is!  It's using AX's drilldown functionality which uses AxHLink.exe to handle dynamics:// URLs, which are passed to the Classes\SysStartupCmd function.  You could also create some custom code there if you wanted to launch the AX client executable directly.

My question I asked some while back should have a great deal of useful information in it here:

[What handles dynamics:// URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21315422/what-handles-dynamics-urls)

Some more can be found: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa834337.aspx

**EDIT:**
It sounds like you are confused or the posts weren't clear enough. I think you have 3 basic options.

1. Dynamics:// URLs are handled by AxHLink.exe and they only seem to handle `drilldown`, `viewalert`, and `viewalertrule`. So if you want to use Dynamics:// URLs, you will need to hi-jack those somehow. There is a pastbin from Jan in that other stack post.
2. Create a custom URI handler and event poller (lot of work) see http://axcoder.blogspot.dk/2010/10/how-to-open-form-in-running-ax-from.html
3. Extend `SysStartupCmd` and then instead of using `Dynamics://` URLs, just call `Ax32.exe -startupCmd` directly and a parameter can be passed to your custom class.

Comment: I read all of your linked article and also the ones linked there, but I don't get an event fired in AX. I added the URL-Protocol, tested with some links like you mentioned in your post and set a breakpoint in the specific class - at not time this breakpoint is hit. Do you have any hints?

Comment: I updated my original post because this comment was too small.

Comment: Well, the described way is correct and it works now. But: **You have to open AX via AX32.exe**. If you open AX via axc-File, the events don't work (at least in my tests). I marked your answer as correct one - perhaps you could add this little but weighty aspect!

Comment: Ah you can still open AXC files, but you open AX32.exe and pass the AXC file and the parameters.

Comment: Yes I believe.  You just create a shortcut that's something like `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics AX\50\Client\Bin\Ax32.exe "c:\MyAxc.axc" -startupCmd=[...]`.  I can't remember the exact syntax, but if you play around with it, you should be able to figure it out.