# I an not able to open an Ax form using a weblink outside AX2012

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I am trying to achieve the same goal which is discussed here([What handles dynamics:// URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21315422/what-handles-dynamics-urls)),
and followed the code example given by "Jan B. Kjeldsen", then I created a HTML page to test that as follows

```
<HTML>
    <Body>
        <a href="dynamics://0/?DrillDown_0?table=Vendtable&value=Test">click here</a>
    </body>
</HTML>
```

when I click at the link in page, No action is taken, even the client is not trying to open.
But when I remove the extra parameters and replace the Drilldown_0 with Drilldown_17 (17 is the inboxID of an existing event in eventInbox table).

```
<HTML>
    <Body>
        <a href="dynamics://0/?DrillDown_17">click here</a>
    </body>
</HTML>
```

It works fine and takes me to the expected vendor record.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the the AX URI handler was not installed?

See [how do I create my own URL protocol? (e.g. so://...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so)

All clients seeing your web page has to have it setup.