# Add custom text to AX 2012 drill-down links

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I want to customize the standard drill-down functionality and add a text parameter to the drill-down URL. I will then parse and use the parameter in the SysStartUpCmdDrillDown or EventDrillDownPoller class like the solution provided by Jan B. Kjeldsen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21316686/2552958).

The standard drill-down link is *dynamics://**Target**/?DrillDown_**RecID**/* :

```
dynamics://0/?DrillDown_5637230378/
```

In previous versions of AX it was possible to modify the RecId to custom text and parse the text once the client is started:

```
dynamics://0/?DrillDown_0MenuItemName=PurchTable&FieldName=PurchId&FieldValue=P000044
```

Unfortunately, in AX 2012 the RecId is checked before the client is started and if it is not a valid int64, the drill-down event is not sent to the client. Since it is not possible to change the RecId to anything other than an integer, @Alex Kwitny suggested in the comments at [that same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21315422/2552958) that you can add the custom text to the drill-down target like this:

```
dynamics://0MenuItemName=PurchTable/?DrillDown_5637230378/
```

The problem I experience with this is that the link now gets confused about which instance to start.

If the target is equal to the value in the *System Admin -> system parameters -> Alerts ->Drill-down target*, a client with the correct server instance is started. When I append the text with my custom text, it always starts the default instance(Which could be different from the instance I intended to start). While this is not ideal, I could work around this issue.

The bigger problem is that it now always starts a new session of the default instance, even if a client session is already started. As far as I can see I cannot write X++ code to solve this issue since the server instance is determined before any code in the client is executed.

**My question is this** - How can I add custom text to the drill-down link while preserving the way the client instance is started: If a client for the instance is already open, it should process the link in the open client, and not start up a new client of the default instance.

Comment: For AX09, I thought it would always launch the default configuration, then just compare the drill down target in the URL to match the configuration. If it was a match, it would continue. Is this behavior not the same in AX12? The code appears to verify the drill down target, so I'd imagine it is still dependent on the default configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably come up with another solution [as mentioned in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21315422/what-handles-dynamics-urls), but there could still be a way.

The URL has two objects that can be modified:

> dynamics://`[Drill-down target(str)]`/?Drilldown_`[Int64]`

According to you, if you modify the `[Drill-down target]`, then it launches AX using the default client config, and that is behavior that you don't want. If you have a matching `[Drill-down target]`, it'll launch in the open client window, which is behavior I can't confirm, but I'll take it at face value and assume you're correct.

So that means the only thing you can modify in the URL is `[int64]`. This is actually a `string` that is converted to an `int64` via `str2int64(...)`, which in turn corresponds to a `RecId`.  **This is where it gets interesting.**

This work all happens in `\Classes\SysStartUpCmdDrillDown\infoRun`.

Well, lucky for you the ranges for the objects are:

- `RecId` - `0 to 9223372036854775807`
- `Int64` - `-9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807`

You can call `minRecId()` and `maxRecId()` to confirm this.

So this means you have `-9223372036854775808 to -1` numbers to work with by calling URLs in this range:

- `dynamics://0/?DrillDown_-1`
- to
- `dynamics://0/?DrillDown_-9223372036854775808`

Then you would modify `\Classes\SysStartUpCmdDrillDown\infoRun` to look for negative numbers, and fork to your custom code.

**HOW** you decide to user these negative #'s is up to you. You can have the first *n-digits* be a table id or a look-up value for a custom table. You can't technically use a `RecId` as part of that negative number because in theory the `RecId` could get up that high (minus 1).