# How to connect a Program with a Protocol like Skype uses (callto:) Outlook uses (mailto:)

Tags: c#, vb.net, browser, protocols

I just wanted to know how to open a desktop app written in vb.net or C# when user visit my website and click a link like:

```
<a href="openit:user_id">Click here</a>
```

what is the simplest way to perform this action?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so

Answer (score 0):

Look up how to register a protocol handler, here may be a good starting point: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx This is generally something that you'd do in your installer.

Comment: i have register that alert protocol into my registry and mentioned the exe file path to be run when that protocol is triggered but nothing happens 
but if i call the program in RUN 
"C:\soft.exe" "alert:me"
then it shows the parameter of alert:me
but not when the browser ask so..