# How to pass argument through custom url to an application

Tags: python, registry, argument-passing, custom-url

I am using windows 7
I want to pass **filename as argument** which  I want to open through custom url.
I followed link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx

My python code is:

```
import os,sys
selectedFileName=(sys.argv)[1]
os.startfile(selectedFileName)
```

My registry setting is:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\cultest]
@="\"URL:cultest Protocol\""
"URL Protocol"="\"\""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\cultest\DefaultIcon]


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\cultest\shell]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\cultest\shell\open]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\cultest\shell\open\command]
@="\"D:\\Test\\argument\\dist\\cultest.exe\" \"%1\""
```

So which url I type in webbrowser/mozila/explorer.
I tried with cultest:"C:/Users/liverpool/Desktop/Hostname.txt" but it didn't work  C:/Users/liverpool/Desktop/Hostname.txt is the file name

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your registry code and screenprint are not the same: 'cultest.exe' and 'curlargu.exe'.

And you have used the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE instead of HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. They point to the same, but it might make a difference. If cultest.exe is your program in the mentioned folder, then this registry code should work. Your browser URL call is correct.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cultest]
@="URL:cultest Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cultest\DefaultIcon]
@="D:\\Test\\argument\\dist\\cultest.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cultest\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cultest\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cultest\shell\open\command]
@="D:\\Test\\argument\\dist\\cultest.exe \"%1\""
```

I used the same REG-file today for my own program and it is working. I noticed some minor differences in the slashes...