# How to create my own URL-handler

Tags: url

I have two links:

1. http:\one
2. UB:\two

Default browser is IE.
In need that second URL was opened in Chrome browser.

I did this:

1. Created and launched reg file which contains:

   ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\docnet]
   @="URL:UB Protocol"
   "URL Protocol"=""

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\docnet\shell]
   @=""

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\docnet\shell\open]

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\docnet\shell\open\command]
   @="C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe %1"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ub]
   @="URL:UB Protocol"
   "URL Protocol"=""

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ub\shell]
   @=""

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ub\shell\open]

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ub\shell\open\command]
   @="C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe %1"
   ```
2. Created link "ub:\two" in Outlook and clicked on it.
3. Profit, but it opens only Chrome browser without going through link. Just empty browser, as i would open it by shortcut.

**How can i make browser to go by link?**

I've seen similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24265292/how-to-pass-argument-through-custom-url-to-an-application) but i found no answer.

Comment: Now i've figured out that a can transfer some parameters in URL like this:
ub:\\-a two

But the problem is that space symbol is encoded by outlook and my key doesn't work.

Comment: I can use url handler to open bat file, that would open Chrome browser and transfer URL. How can i do that?